# How to reset input value if a condition fails Primefaces3.5

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem. I am trying to save a information into the database, and before that I check some conditions like if-else like:

```
if(condition){
        //Some Action
}else{
   getFacesContext().addMessage(null,MessageFactory.getMessage(ResourceBundle.FACES_BUNDLE.getName(), FacesBundle.LANDLINE_NUMBER_SHOULD_BE_TEN.getName()));
   getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
   return;
}
```

and When the condition does not match I would like to restore the previous values of the input field.

[image]

In that case, it was `22` in place of `ss`. but the field does not take input except numbers. So the validation fails and shows an message `Invalid Input` via growl.

How can I also reset the value of the field `ss` to `22` in java?

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

You can use default validator that comes with JSF

```
 <p:inputText id="number" value="" label="Number">  
        <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0" maximum="99" />  
 </p:inputText>  
 <p:message for="number" />
```

But if you reset the filed with old value, user may not know what he's entered. However you will not submit until validation success.

Comment: no Actually I want it to work like `<p:resetInput>` but from Java Side. I even tried `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("id")` but it did not work! :(

Answer (score 0):

Since the input text component implements EditableValueHolder you can call EditableValueHolder.resetValue() on the input component (or call the more convenient RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset(inputTextId)) and then re-render it by calling RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(inputTextId) if it isn't already being re-rendered through the update attribute of p:ajax.